# Angularjs controller is breaking my expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I just finished the CodeSchool course on Angularjs and have been messing with updating a current website of mine.  Funnily enough, if I write controller or directive code, it doesn't work.  But it seems to work fine using anyone else's code.  Therefore, I strongly suspect something is wrong with my app code, but I just can't seem to find it for the life of me.

Omitted code is represented by `...omit` and is available if its actually relevant and I am wrong.

**Here's the relevant html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="main" lang="en">
<head>
    ...omit
    <!--Script Includes-->
    <script src="/script/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    ...omit
    <div class="container content">
        ...omit
        <div id="schedule">
            <h1>See us in Concert</h1>
            <ul class="list-group" ng-controller="ScheduleController as schedCtrl">
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ 5 + 5 }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Highlights <span class="badge">{{schedCtrl.highlight.count}}</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Upcoming <span class="badge">{{schedCtrl.now.count}}</span></li> 
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="next in schedCtrl.future">{{next.month}} <span class="badge">{{next.count}}</span></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        ...omit
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And 'main.js':**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('main', [ ]);

    app.controller('ScheduleController', [$http, function ($http) {
        // Some test data
        this.highlight.count = 2;
        this.now.count = 5;
        this.future = [{month: "June", count: 7}, {month: "July", count: 4}];
    }]);
})();
```

I've read over it several times and searched countless pages for a solution but I just can't seem to get it to work.  Rather than treating the expressions as expressions it simply treats them as text, printing out the expression itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. Going by simpler way of coding use the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js" ></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container content">
        <div id="schedule">
            <h1>See us in Concert</h1>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ 5 + 5 }}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Highlights <span class="badge">{{highlight.count}}</span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Upcoming <span class="badge">{{now.count}}</span></li> 
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="x in future">{{x.month}} <span class="badge">{{x.count}}</span></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
<script>
//module declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    // Some test data
    $scope.highlight = {count:2};
    $scope.now = {count : 5};
    $scope.future = [{month: "June", count: 7}, {month: "July", count: 4}];
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, but I would like to know what those errors are.  I understand you want to make it simple; however my focus is on extensible.

Comment: You need to define $scope inside controller instead of $http. You cannot directly define a property of object without defining object itself. Moreover ... try Lynda, its got better tutorials.

Comment: I was going to use $http later for loading json but thank you.  I will check that out because the CodeSchool course taught to use this. instead of $scope.  It didn't make sense to me as I am used to native oop like Java or C++ but I am not experienced with JS as you can see.

Comment: Yep, with $scope binding cannot happen whatsoever you do in controller. You may inject both, but atleast $scope is required.

Comment: using $scope is not a solution, since it will be removed in later versions. See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
(function () { })();
```

angular isn't defined anymore inside.

(FYI: The above is a self-executing anonymous function.
http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/ )

So you must change it to

`(function (angular) {})(angular);`

also inside your controller add this

```
var self = this; 
self.highlight.count =2;
```

it's good practice to not use 'this' but reassign it to a variable so your scopes don't get messed up. That way there is no need to use $scope (which will get dropped in later versions)

Also to figure out these errors, look in your developper tools in chrome or IE what javascript errors you get. All angular errors have links to relevant pages. Though your error will have been 'angular' is undefined.